# Ubuntu 18.04 crash due to startup application

Tags: gnome, crash, multi-touch, touchegg

I am new to Ubuntu and had been running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS dual boot with Windows 10.

I just installed `touchegg` and added it in startup applications using the following procedure : 
https://www.maketecheasier.com/add-multitouch-gestures-ubuntu/

after reboot, once I try to log in the desktop won't open. it black screen with the message: `Error found when loading /home/$user/.xprofile:`

[image]

Is there any way to prevent the application from running at startup or prevent the crash? any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`.xprofile` is not there in a default Ubuntu install (at least not in 19.10). The program must have created it.

The error indicates that `.xprofile` attempts to load a tool, `synclient`, but it is not there.

This to me suggests you are using the more up-to-date `libinput` driver for mouse and touchpad rather than the more antiquated `synaptics` driver. `synclient` indeed is a tool that belongs to the `synaptics` driver. It is installed along with the package `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`.

You have a few options.

**Option 1. Do not use touchegg, which requires a somewhat older driver**

You may then remove the hidden file `.xprofile` in your home folder and remove the software. The easiest way is with two terminal commands:

```
rm /home/$USER/.xprofile
sudo apt install touchegg
```

You can see the file if you check "Show hidden filed" in the file manager (you can do so with the hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>).

**Option 2. Switch to the synaptics driver**

I do not recommend this. General performance and experience using the synaptics driver remains to be awaited. This also requires changes to your system setup. You will also see that the number of configurable options in "Settings" - "Mouse and touchpad" will have greatly decreased.

Switching to the `synaptics` driver may be done by removing `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` and installing `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and rebooting. Reverse the changes can be done in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.
Opened up a terminal in log screen using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get remove touchegg
sudo apt-get remove geis-tools
rm /home/$USER/.xprofile
sudo systemctl restart gdm3
```